# Find k value where the function is a pdf

Tags: probability-distributions

Find k value where the function is a pdf

(a) $kx^6(1-x)^4$, for $0 < x < 1, 0$ otherwise

(b) $kx^2(4-x)^3$, for $0 < x < 4$. $0$ otherwise

---

my attempt

(a) $$\int_{0}^{1} kx^6(1-x)^4 dx$$

Do I just solve this on $[0,1]?$

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is to convert from a .pdf to a .tex.
Anyway, getting to the point, you need to integrate it and figure out the precise value of $k$ for which the integral is equal to $1$. So yes your integral is correct.

Comment: Would there be an easier way to integrate something like this? The only way I can think of is to expand it fully

Comment: it's not hard to expand it fully, it'll take longer trying to find a way to integrate it nicely :) If you're careful you can use the fact that $(1-x)^5$ differentiates to a constant multiple of $(1-x)^4$ but the presence of the $x^6$ term in front makes it difficult to exploit this.

Comment: you can use easily integration by parts 6 times. It is not hard to figure out the result just with your head. Try it.

Comment: Using the binomial theorem,
$$
(1-x)^4 = 1 -4x +6x^2 -4x^3 +x^4.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the general case of
$$I_{m,n}=\int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^n \,dx$$ Let
$$x=\sin^2(t) \implies dx=2\sin(t)\cos(t)\,dt$$ making
$$I_{m,n}=2 \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \sin ^{2 m+1}(t) \cos ^{2 n+1}(t)\,dt$$ and using the usual reduction formula
$$I_{m,n}=\frac{\Gamma (m+1)\, \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (m+n+2)}$$